# Unable to Efficiently Compute the Weighted Average, with weight $\overline{r}$, for points in a closed region?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, numerical-integration, numerics, finite-element-method

In a [previous post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/163601/how-to-accurately-and-efficiently-compute-the-weighted-average-with-weight-ov), I wanted to compute the weighted average, with weight $\overline{r}(x,y)$, of the whole cartesian plane. This was not possible since the integrals did not converge.

Instead I'm computing the weighted average of points inside Region $\mathcal{C}$.

The definition of $\overline{r}(x,y)$ is the average ray function

> Suppose we have curve $\mathcal{C}$ and a ray, from $\mathbf{p}\in\mathcal{C}$, rotating full circle at $\Delta \theta$ increments while intersecting $\mathcal{C}$. We will denote the intersections as $\left\{\mathbf{q}_i\right\}_{i=1}^{n}$ (for $n$ intersections) and the length of the ray as $r_i = \|{\mathbf{q}_i}\mathbf
>   - \mathbf p\|$.
>
> Then as $\Delta \theta\to0$, the **average radius function** is $\overline{r}(\mathbf{p})=\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}r_i\right)/{n}$

For star shaped curves, one can use an alternate and simpler definition

$$\overline{r}(\mathbf{p})=\frac1{2\pi}\oint_{\mathbf {q}_1\in\mathcal C}\|\mathbf {q}_1-\mathbf p\|\,\mathrm d\theta.$$

Thanks to @Rahul, in [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103134/help-finding-the-points-inside-non-star-closed-shape-with-the-highest-averag/163619#163619), I have a code that can implement $\overline{r}(x,y)$. For example, if $\mathcal{C}$ is defined by $x^2+y^2+\sin(4x)+\sin(4y)=4$

```
curve = DiscretizeRegion[
      ImplicitRegion[
       x^2+y^2+Sin[4*x]+Sin[4*y] == 4, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -4, 4}}], {{-3, 3},
    {-4, 4}}, AccuracyGoal -> 8]
    q = MeshCoordinates[curve];
    edges = First /@ MeshCells[curve, 1];
    signedAngle[a_, b_] := Arg[(Complex @@ a)/(Complex @@ b)]
    avgRadius[p_] := 
     1/(2 \[Pi]) Abs[Sum[Module[{q1, q2, r, d\[Theta]}, q1 = q[[First@e]];
         q2 = q[[Last@e]];
         r = EuclideanDistance[p, (q1 + q2)/2];(*midpoint approximation*)
         d\[Theta] = signedAngle[q1 - p, q2 - p];
         r d\[Theta]], {e, edges}]]
   avgRadius[{x, y}]
```

---

**Edit:** **A faster code can be implemented using @HenrySchumacer's answer in the** [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163619/34171).

```
avgRadiusFunction[curve_MeshRegion] := 
  Module[{q, e1, e2}, q = MeshCoordinates[curve];
   {e1, e2} = Transpose[Developer`ToPackedArray[MeshCells[curve, 1][[All, 1]]]];
   With[{q11 = q[[e1, 1]], q12 = q[[e1, 2]], q21 = q[[e2, 1]], q22 = q[[e2, 2]]},
    Compile[{{p, _Real, 1}},
     Module[{u11, u12, u21, u22, r, dθ, r2squared, r2, p1, p2},
      p1 = Part[p, 1];
      p2 = Part[p, 2];
      u11 = q11 - p1;
      u12 = q12 - p2;
      u21 = q21 - p1;
      u22 = q22 - p2;
      r2squared = (u21^2 + u22^2);
      dθ = ArcTan[(u11 u21 + u12 u22)/r2squared, (u12 u21 - u11 u22)/r2squared];
      r2 = Sqrt[r2squared];
      (RotateRight[r2] + r2).dθ/(4. Pi)
      ],
     RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
     Parallelization -> True]
    ]
   ];
curve = DiscretizeRegion[ ImplicitRegion[x^2+y^2+Sin[4*x]+Sin[4*y] == 4, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -4, 4}}], {{-3, 3},{-4, 4}}, AccuracyGoal -> 8]
f = avgRadiusFunction[curve];
```

---

We can plot the contour of $\overline{r}(x,y)$ on $\mathcal{C}$.

```
k = ContourPlot[f[{x, y}], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, 
  Exclusions -> None, Contours -> 100, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image: Center]

Hence the weighted average in $\mathcal{C}$ is

$$\begin{array}{cc}
{x_w=\frac{\int\int_{\mathcal{C}}x\overline{r}(x,y) \ dA }{\int\int_{\mathcal{C}}\overline{r}(x,y) \ dA}} & {
y_w=\frac{\int\int_{\mathcal{C}} y\overline{r}(x,y)  \ dA}{\int\int_{\mathcal{C}}\overline{r}(x,y) \ dA} }\end{array}$$

However, even for the simplest double integrals, I'm unable to approximate using `NIntegrate` In less than an hour.

```
x_w=(NIntegrate[x*avgRadius[{x,y}],{x,-10,10},
{y,-10,10}])/(NIntegrate[avgRadius[{x,y}],{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10}])

y_w=(NIntegrate[y*avgRadius[{x,y}],{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10}])/(NIntegrate[avgRadius[{x,y}],{x,-10,10},{y,-10,10}])
```

> How do I do accurately and efficiently approximate the weighted average of the $x$ and $y$-coordinates over curve $\mathcal{C}$ with weights $\overline{r}(x,y)$?

"Accurately" means the error should be less than .00001. "Efficently" means computing the integral under $15$ minutes? I am unable to do so using `NIntegrate`

Comment: Your main issue is that your function is too slow. Also you shouldn't keep calling `avgRadius[{x, y}]` over-and-over. Cache that result. I'd suggest replacing the `EuclideanDistance` with its appropriate symbolic definition, calculating `symRad = avgRadius[{x, y}]` and trying to `Compile` that result (using `Compile[ ... , Evaluate@symRad, ...]`). This will hopefully be fast enough to actually compute this integral.

Comment: You should also point to [this old post of yours](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103134/help-finding-the-points-inside-non-star-closed-shape-with-the-highest-averag/163619#163619).

Comment: @b3m2a1 Why is there a singularity?

Comment: @Arbuja never mind it's just a strong peak (which makes more sense). If you just do a `Table` and `ListPlot3D` Mathematica clips it. Then there's a different issue in the `NIntegrate`. All I know is it's unhappy with your function for one reason or another.

Comment: Also your `AccuracyGoal` is probably way overkill. Try dropping it to 3 or 4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the function `avgRadiusFunction` from [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/103134/help-finding-the-points-inside-non-star-closed-shape-with-the-highest-averag/163619#163619) 
(hardened version!) and using the mass matrix from the finite element method (and coarsening the mesh considerably, this can be done as follows:

```
implicitcurve =  ImplicitRegion[ x^2 + y^2 + Sin[4*x] + Sin[4*y] == 4, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -4, 4}}];
ρ = 0.01;
ρfine = 0.000001;
curvecoarse = DiscretizeRegion[implicitcurve, {{-3, 3}, {-4, 4}},  MaxCellMeasure -> ρ]
curvefine = DiscretizeRegion[implicitcurve, {{-3, 3}, {-4, 4}},  MaxCellMeasure -> ρfine];
```

[image]

As integration domain, I use simply the bounded domain enclosed by `curvecoarse`.

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
domain = ToElementMesh[curvecoarse, "MeshOrder" -> 2, MaxCellMeasure -> ρ];
domain["Wireframe"]
```

[image]

This computes the mass matrix:

```
mass = Module[{vd, sd, cdata, x, y, u},
  vd = NDSolve`VariableData[{"DependentVariables","Space"} -> {{u}, {x, y}}];
  sd = NDSolve`SolutionData[{"Space"} -> {domain}];
  cdata = InitializePDECoefficients[vd, sd, "MassCoefficients" -> {{1}}]; 
  DiscretizePDE[cdata, InitializePDEMethodData[vd, sd], sd]["MassMatrix"]
  ];
```

And this computes the integral $\int_{\operatorname{domain}} \bar r(x,y) \, \operatorname{d} x \, \operatorname{d} y$

```
{x,y}=Transpose[domain["Coordinates"]];
avgradii = avgRadiusFunction[curvefine][domain["Coordinates"]];
totalavgradius = Total[mass.avgradii]
```

> 21.4127

The $x_w$ and $y_w$ can be obtained like this:

```
xw = (x.mass.avgradii)/totalavgradius
yw = (y.mass.avgradii)/totalavgradius
```

> -0.0689768
>
> -0.0690877

Of course, you are free to decrease with the edge length parameter `ρ` which controls the accuracy. For example, with `ρ = 0.001;ρfine = 0.000001;` I get

```
xw = (x.mass.avgradii)/totalavgradius
yw = (y.mass.avgradii)/totalavgradius
```

> -0.0690308
>
> -0.0690308

Comment: Nice. I clearly need to get comfortable with FEMs.

Comment: How do I use this to solve $x_w$ and $y_w$? Do I take `s=x*avgRadiusFunction[curve]` and apply `Total[mass.s[curvfine][domain["Coordinates"]]]`

Answer (score 4):

I mentioned this in the comments, but we'll tackle this via compilation and a more manageable `AccuracyGoal`:

```
curve =
  DiscretizeRegion[
   ImplicitRegion[
    x^2 + y^2 + Sin[4*x] + Sin[4*y] == 
     4, {{x, -3, 3}, {y, -4, 4}}], {{-3, 3}, {-4, 4}}, 
   AccuracyGoal -> 4];
q = MeshCoordinates[curve];
edges = First /@ MeshCells[curve, 1];
avgRadius[p_] :=

  1/(2 π) Abs[
    Sum[Module[{q1, q2, d1, d2, r, dθ}, q1 = q[[First@e]];
      q2 = q[[Last@e]];
      r = Norm[p - (q1 + q2)/2];(*midpoint approximation*)

      d1 = q1 - p;
      d2 = q2 - p;
      dθ =
       Arg[(d1[[1]] + I*d1[[2]])/(d2[[1]] + I*d2[[2]])];
      r dθ], {e, edges}]];
symbRad = avgRadius[{x, y}];
compSym =
  Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}},
   Evaluate@symbRad,
   RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False},
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];
```

Then we can see how long it takes on a reasonably small grid:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
  heights =
    Table[
     compSym[x, y],
     {x, -10, 10, .1},
     {y, -10, 10, .1}
     ];
  ][[1]]

3.49649
```

Which is still mad slow. So the `NIntegrate` will probably take a looong time.

And so first we check to see if we messed up and introduced a `"MainEvaluate"`:

```
<< CompiledFunctionTools`
pstr = CompilePrint[compSym];
StringContainsQ[pstr, "MainEvaluate"]

False
```

And it turns out we didn't.

Now plotting those `heights`:

```
ListPlot3D[heights, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: asdasd]

This seems like the kind of `NIntegrate` should be able to handle. So:

```
NIntegrate[
 compSym[x, y],
 {x, -10, 10},
 {y, -10, 10}
 ]

NIntegrate::slwcon: Numerical integration converging too slowly; suspect one of the following: singularity, value of the integration is 0, highly oscillatory integrand, or WorkingPrecision too small.

142.029
```

And so there's something in your domain making `NIntegrate` unhappy.

The other integrals can also be handled via compilation, e.g.:

```
compXSym =
  Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}},
   Evaluate[x * symbRad],
   RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False},
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];

compYSym =
  Compile[{{x, _Real}, {y, _Real}},
   Evaluate[y * symbRad],
   RuntimeOptions -> {"EvaluateSymbolically" -> False},
   CompilationTarget -> "C"
   ];
```

But fundamentally `NIntegrate` is unhappy with something in your problem and it's worth trying to figure out what that is.

Comment: Maybe the code from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/163619/34171) could help?